# How to filter view content by book outline?

Tags: views, nodes

How can a book page include a view (as a block) that lists all items of a specific content type that are also part of the book outline and are children of the current book page?

This is intended to show a grid of teasers (videos), navigated by a table of contents.

A contextual filter may be the way to go, but unfortunately, there’s not much in the way of book outline information available to select from.

I could imagine a workaround where I would create a taxonomy that mirrors the book outline and use that for the contextual filter. If possible, I’d like to avoid this redundancy, though.

Any idea how this would work?